# SSIS Deployment/Setup issue

Tags: sql-server-2008, ssis

I have an SSIS 2008 Package that imports some data and then writes out a text file to a local folder on the computer.  Everything built, deployed and installed fine, and in my XML configuration file I have a property to set the location of the local folder.  I also use an operating system Environment Variable to redirect the location of the XML Configuration file at run time.  On my development machine I set the drop-off folder location to C:\Temp, but on the target computer I want this drop-off folder set to E:\SSIS\FileDropOff and I make that configuration setting change at install time.  The setup for everything looks fine to me, configuration file looks ok, there were no warnings or errors in the validation check at install time, the Environment Variable is pointing to the right place, and the SSIS Package is installed in the SQL Server MSDB database.

The problem is when the SSIS Package runs on the target computer, it keeps writing the text file to C:\Temp.  No matter what I do I can't seem to get it to write to the E:\SSIS\FileDropOff folder.  It's like the SSIS Package is stuck on C:\Temp and is ignoring the the XML configuration file setting on the target machine.  In the SQL Agent running the SSIS Package I even tried checking the box on the Job Step Properties screen, Data Sources tab and set the Connection String to E:\SSIS\FileDropOff and it still doesn't work.

Is there any place I could be missing where the SSIS Package is looking at C:\Temp?  Could there be a cached value someplace that I am not aware of that forcing the package to stick on C:\Temp?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1.) Try restarting your SQL Agent Service. If I remember correctly, it caches environment variables.

2.) Try setting up a package variable and using that to set the connection string instead of the xml file directly.

Answer (score 0):

I believe it's a common mistake when moving between environments (i.e., dev - test - prod) to forget to right click on your package in the new environment and select the latest XML config file. So what's happening is your package is still looking at the old XML config file. You need to right click, and choose to browse and open the one intended for the specific environment.

Make sense? 
If you didn't do this you may have unintentionally overwritten your config file.